# Unable to import FFmpeg based MediaPlayer

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi3

I have installed `ffmpeg` and `ffpyplayer` on `raspberrry pi 3` (raspbain stretch).
I get an import error when I try to do this:

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
```

This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ffpyplayer/player/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ffpyplayer.player.player import MediaPlayer

ImportError: /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ffpyplayer/player/player.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: x264_levels
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: build with: `LDFLAGS= -lx264 -laacplus -lrtmp -lmp3lame -lass -lopencore-amrnb -lopencore-amrwb -lspeex -ltheora -lvorbis`

Comment: I am new to this, could you please tell me what commands to use. Thank you very much. @PedroLobito

Comment: You'll probably need to recompile ffmpeg with the above flags

Comment: after recompiling with the above flags I still get the same error! @PedroLobito

Comment: Also I am getting many warnings when I run make command: `CC fftools/ffmpeg_opt.o
fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c: In function ‘add_input_streams’:
fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c:777:13: warning: ‘codec’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             if (st->codec->lowres) {
             ^~
In file included from fftools/cmdutils.h:30:0,
                 from fftools/ffmpeg.h:28,
                 from fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c:23:
./libavformat/avformat.h:878:21: note: declared here
     AVCodecContext *codec;
                     ^~~~~`

_Is this somehow related?_ **Thank you very much** @Pedro

Comment: You may open a new question for that specific error, make sure the answer doesn't exist already on SO.